# WebAPI - Resolve controller and action manually from the request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, session-state

I wanted to make my WebAPI application change the used `SessionStateBehavior` based on action attributes like that:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/test")]
    [SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required)]    // <--- This modifies the behavior
    public async Task<int> Test(){}
```

It seems, however, that the only place I can change the session behavior is inside my `HttpApplication`'s `Application_PostAuthorizeRequest` (or in similar places, early in the request lifetime), otherwise I get this error:

```
'HttpContext.SetSessionStateBehavior' can only be invoked before 'HttpApplication.AcquireRequestState' event is raised.
```

So, at that point no controller or action resolution is done, so I don't know what action will be called in order to check its attributes.
So, I am thinking of resolving the action manually.

I started with these lines of code to resolve the controller first:

```
 var httpCtx = HttpContext.Current;
 var ctrlSel = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector)) as IHttpControllerSelector;
 var actionSel = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IHttpActionSelector)) as IHttpActionSelector;
 HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor = ctrlSel.SelectController(httpCtx.Request);
```

But in the last line I can't get the proper `HttpRequestMessage` from the request.
Any idea ho how get that?
This is not inside a controller, so I don't have it ready there.
Or, is there a better way to do this?
I am trying to see the disassembled code of the framework to copy portions of it, but I am quite lost at this point...

---

*UPDATE:*

This is the closest I got to resolving the action manually, but it doesn't work:

I have registered those two services:

```
            container.RegisterType<IHttpControllerSelector, DefaultHttpControllerSelector>();
            container.RegisterType<IHttpActionSelector, ApiControllerActionSelector>();
```

...and try to get the required session behavior like that:

```
    private  SessionStateBehavior GetDesiredSessionBehavior(HttpContext httpCtx)
    {
        var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
        var diResolver = config.Services;
        var ctrlSel = diResolver.GetService(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector)) as IHttpControllerSelector;
         var actionSel = diResolver.GetService(typeof(IHttpActionSelector)) as IHttpActionSelector;

        if (ctrlSel is null || actionSel is null)
        {
            return DefaultSessionBehavior;
        }


        var method = new HttpMethod(httpCtx.Request.HttpMethod);
        var requestMsg = new HttpRequestMessage(method, httpCtx.Request.Url);
        requestMsg.Properties.Add(HttpPropertyKeys.RequestContextKey, httpCtx.Request.RequestContext);
        requestMsg.Properties.Add(HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey, config);
        httpCtx.Request.Headers.Cast<string>().ForEach(x => requestMsg.Headers.Add(x, httpCtx.Request.Headers[x]));


        var httpRouteData = httpCtx.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
        var routeData = config.Routes.GetRouteData(requestMsg);
        requestMsg.Properties.Add(HttpPropertyKeys.HttpRouteDataKey, routeData);
        requestMsg.SetRequestContext(new HttpRequestContext(){RouteData = routeData });
        requestMsg.SetConfiguration(config);
        var route = config.Routes["DefaultApi"];
        requestMsg.SetRouteData(routeData ?? route.GetRouteData(config.VirtualPathRoot, requestMsg));

        var routeHandler = httpRouteData.RouteHandler ?? new WebApiConfig.SessionStateRouteHandler();
        var httpHandler = routeHandler.GetHttpHandler(httpCtx.Request.RequestContext);
        if (httpHandler is IHttpAsyncHandler httpAsyncHandler)
        {
            httpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(httpCtx, ar => httpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(ar), null);
        }
        else
        {
            httpHandler.ProcessRequest(httpCtx);
        }

        var values = requestMsg.GetRouteData().Values; // Hm this is empty and makes the next call fail...
        HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor = ctrlSel.SelectController(requestMsg);

        IHttpController controller = controllerDescriptor?.CreateController(requestMsg);
        if (controller == null)
        {
            return DefaultSessionBehavior;
        }

        var ctrlContext = CreateControllerContext(requestMsg, controllerDescriptor, controller);
        var actionCtx = actionSel.SelectAction(ctrlContext);
        var attr = actionCtx.GetCustomAttributes<ActionSessionStateAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        return attr?.Behavior ?? DefaultSessionBehavior;
    }
```

I have an alternative hack to make it work (send header values from the client to modify the session behavior), but it would be nice if the version above worked.

**UPDATE:**

Eventually, I went with setting the session behavior based on a client header value and validating the validity of sending that header based on the action attributes later-on in the request lifetime. If someone can solve the action resolution code I was fighting with above, feel free to post the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is going to be helpful for you, but I was just following a Pluralsight course (https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=implementing-restful-aspdotnet-web-api) and in the Versioning chapter the author shows how to implement a controller selector where he **does** have access to the request.

The controller selector looks like:

```
public class CountingKsControllerSelector : DefaultHttpControllerSelector
{
  private HttpConfiguration _config;
  public CountingKsControllerSelector(HttpConfiguration config)
    : base(config)
  {
    _config = config;
  }

  public override HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
  {
    var controllers = GetControllerMapping();

    var routeData = request.GetRouteData();

    var controllerName = (string)routeData.Values["controller"];

    HttpControllerDescriptor descriptor;

    if (controllers.TryGetValue(controllerName, out descriptor))
    {
      [...]

      return descriptor;
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

And it's registered in `WebApiConfig` with:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector),
  new CountingKsControllerSelector(config));
```

Comment: No, unfortunately this won't help. I have already tried changing the session behavior inside the registered `IHttpControllerSelector` service and based on controller attributes, but it fails with the error message posted on my question. So, it needs to happen before that service is used by the framework.

Comment: @user2173353 - OK. Would you rather I delete my answer, so your question would show up as with zero answers; or just leave it so others would see that this is not what you need?

Comment: You can leave it. I think I am about to find a possible solution to this, so most likely I will post it here in a bit. ;) Thanks.